# Find monotonic function with boundary constraints

Tags: polynomials, monotone-functions

I need to find a function $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ where $x \in [0, T]$ with the following conditions:

- Monotonic function
- Class $C^4$ i.e. differentiable at least 4 times
- $f(0) = 0$
- $f(T) = 1$
- $\dot{f}(0) = 1$
- $\dot{f}(T) = 1$
- $\ddot{f}(0) = 0$
- $\ddot{f}(T) = 0$
- $\dddot{f}(0) = 0$
- $\dddot{f}(T) = 0$
- $\ddddot{f}(0) = 0$
- $\ddddot{f}(T) = 0$

I tried with a polynomial function with high enough degree, imposing all the initial and final conditions, but it always come up non-monotonic.
Any tip?

Comment: Yes, it's piecewise polynomials, so it doesn't help since I cannot impose (easily) the monotonicity

Comment: Which function have you found, that fulfill all properties except the monotonicity? I have not found any polynomials of degrees 5 or less.

Comment: No, you need at least a polynomial of degree 10 to impose all the conditions (except monotonicity).

Comment: Taking a polynomial of degree 10, $f(x)=\sum_{k  =1}^{10} a_k x^{k}$, I obtain that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for $n \in \{ 0, \ldots, 4 \}$ implies that $a_0 = \ldots = a_4 = 0$. Right? And $$f^{(4)}(L) = 5040 L^6 + 3024 L^5 + 1680 L^4 + 840 L^3 + 360 L^2 + 120 L + 24 = 0$$ only has complex solutions $L$, so isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: Where is this task from?

Answer (score 3):

This partial answers computes the optimal polynomial solutions for degrees up to $14$.

In order to work on a fixed-size interval, put $g(x)=\frac{f(Tx)}{T}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ (so that conversely, $p(t)=Tg(\frac{t}{T})$ for $t\in [0,T]$). Put also $h=g'$. Then the problem can be restated as : find a ${\cal C}^3$ map $h: [0,1]\to {\mathbb R}$ with $I(h)=\int_0^1 h(x)dx=\frac{1}{T}$ and

$$h\geq 0,h(0)=h(1)=1,h^{(k)}(0)=h^{(k)}(1)=0 \ (1\leq k\leq 3) \label{1}\tag{1}$$

Then, for a given $d$, if we denote by $P_d$ the set of all polynomials $h$ of degree $d$ satisfying \eqref{1}, define $m_d$ to be the inf of $I(h)$ when $h$ varies in $P_d$. Thus, $\frac{1}{m_d}$ will be the largest value of $T$ such that there is a degree-$d$ polynomial solution on $[0,T]$.

As noted in Alex Ravsky's answer, by \eqref{1} there is a polynomial $q$ such that $h(x)=1+((x(1-x)))^4q(x)$, and $q$ has degree $d_q=d-9$.

For each $d$ in the range $[9,14]$, we find a finite $S=S_d \subseteq [0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and nonnegative coefficients $(c_s)_{s\in S}$ such that the following identity holds for any $h$ of degree $\leq d$ satisfying \eqref{1}, by linear algebra :

$$
I(h)=m_d+\sum_{s\in S_d} c_s(h(s)+h(1-s)) \label{2}\tag{2}
$$

Thus \eqref{2} shows that $I(h)\geq m_d$. It will be convenient in what follows to use the shorthand $z=x(1-x)$, and $\pi_S(x)=\prod_{s\in S,1-s\in S}(x-s)$ (note that the product is on a set not a multiset, so $\frac{1}{2}$ is counted only once).

When $d=9$ or $10$, we have $m_d=\frac{187}{315}\approx 0.59,S_d=\lbrace\frac{1}{2}\rbrace,c_s=\frac{64}{315}$ and $h=\pi_S^2(1+4z)(1+16z^2)$ is an optimal solution of degree $9$ in $x$.

When $d=11$ or $12$, we have $m_d=\frac{79747}{196875} \approx 0.4,S_d=\lbrace\alpha\rbrace$ where $\alpha$ is the smallest root of $\alpha^2-\alpha-\frac{5}{22}, c_\alpha=\frac{64}{315}$ and $h=\pi_S^2p^2(4(pz)^3+3(pz)^2+2(pz)+1)$ (where $p=\frac{22}{5}$) is an optimal solution of degree $11$ in $x$.

When $d=13$ or $14$, we have $m_d=\frac{71353}{240625} \approx 0.29, S_d=\lbrace\frac{1}{2},\alpha\rbrace$ where $\alpha$ is the smallest root of $\alpha^2-\alpha-\frac{5}{26}, c_{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{256}{2079}, c_\alpha=\frac{1485172}{6496875}$ and $h=\pi_S^2\big(\frac{2377651456}{3125}z^3 + \frac{9377472}{625}z^2 + \frac{194688}{125}z + \frac{2704}{25}\big)$  is an optimal solution of degree $13$ in $x$.

Here's what the optimal solution in degree $13$ and its derivative look like (suitably rescaled) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Too long for a comment, but not a full solution.**

This solution is quite complicated and only works for $T > 1$ (but should be modifiable for $T \in (0, 1)$), but it is the only one I have been able to come up. Note that for this function, the 4 above can be replaced by any other positive integer, i.e. the function is $C^{\infty}$ and $f^{(n)}(0) = f^{(n)}(L) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, which suggest that there must be a simpler solution.

I started with
$$
g_L \colon [0, L] \to [0, 1], \ 
x \mapsto \begin{cases}
x, & \text{if } x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right), \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, L -\frac{1}{2}\right], \\
x - L + 1, & \text{if } x \in \left(L - \frac{1}{2}, L \right].
\end{cases}
$$
Note that the value of $\frac{1}{2}$ is chosen pretty arbitrarily.

It looks like this (for $L = 2.2$):
[image]
It clearly fulfils all above mentioned properties and is monotonically increasing, except *not being differentiable at two points*.

We now remedy this by "smoothing out the kinks".
For the first kink (I leave the second one to you) consider $h(x) = \exp(-x^{-1}) \cdot \mathbb{1}_{x > 0}(x)$ and $p(x) := \frac{h(x)}{h(x) + h(1 - x)}$, which  are in $C^{\infty}$ (but not analytical).
Now consider the smoothed version
$$
f_L \colon [0, L] \to [0, 1], \ 
x \mapsto \begin{cases}
x, & \text{if } x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{4}\right), \\
\frac{1}{2} p\left(\frac{10 x + 1}{7}\right)\cdot p(5 -  5x), & \text{if } x \in \left[\frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}\right), \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if } x \in \left[\frac{1}{2}, L -\frac{1}{2}\right], \\
x - L + 1, & \text{if } x \in \left(L - \frac{1}{2}, L \right],
\end{cases}
$$
which looks like this
[image]
I am not sure if $f_L$ is $C^{\infty}$ at $x = \frac{1}{4}$, but there definitely is a way to properly smoothen $g_L$ out.

Comment: I like the idea of making piece-wise functions to smooth out, but I don't think this is a valid solution. The second derivative of the first piece is zero everywhere, but the second derivative of the second piece is not.

Comment: @MicheleTuloskiFurci But the derivative of the second piece doesn't matter because you have only boundary conditions, right?

Comment: But to be differentiable 4 times you need all the derivatives up to the 3rd continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Let us look for a polynomial $f$ satisfying the conditions. Let $\dot{f}=1+p$. Putting $p(x)=Ax^4(x-T)^4q(x)$ for some constant $A$, and $f(x)=\int_0^x 1+p(t)dt$, we satisfy all conditions but $f(T)=1$ and the monotonicity. The latter is satisfied iff $1+p(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0,T]$.

One of the simplest choices for $q$ is to put $q\equiv 1$. Then we have $1=f(T)=T+\tfrac{AT^9}{630}$, which gives $A$. When $T\le 1$, $A\ge 0$ and all conditions are satisfied. If $A<0$ then the minimum $m=1+A\left(\tfrac T2\right)^8$ of $1+p(x)$ is attained when $x=\tfrac T2$. Then $m=\tfrac{315-187T}{128 T}$, and the conditions are satisfied when $m\ge 0$, that is when $T\le \tfrac {315}{187}$. It this range of $T$ sufficient for your needs or should we try to extend it using a more complex $q$?

A graph of $f$ for $T=\tfrac {315}{187}$:

[image]

Comment: So this solution is only valid if $T \in \left( 0, \frac{315}{187}\right]$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes.

Comment: @AlexRavsky In my answer I push your ideas a few steps further.

Answer (score 0):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which generates a polynomial feasible function. Here

n = polynomial degree,
xmax = L,
px = found polynomial

```
n = 11;
xmax = 1.7;
Clear[p, x, px]
p[x_] := Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 1, n}]
r1 = {D[p[x], x] - 1, D[p[x], x, x] - 0, D[p[x], x, x, x] - 0, D[p[x], x, x, x, x] - 0} /. {x -> 0};
r2 = {p[x] - 1, D[p[x], x] - 1, D[p[x], x, x] - 0, D[p[x], x, x, x] - 0, D[p[x], x, x, x, x] - 0} /. {x -> xmax};
rs = Join[r1, r2];
dx = 1/(2 n);
dp = D[p[x], x];
rest = Table[dp >= 1/n, {x, dx, xmax - dx, dx}];
restrs = Join[rest, Thread[rs == 0]];
vars = Table[Subscript[a, k], {k, 1, n}];
sol = FindInstance[restrs, vars];
If[Length[sol] > 0, {px = p[x] /. sol; Plot[px, {x, 0, xmax}], dpx = D[px, x]; Plot[{dpx, 0}, {x, 0, xmax}], px}, Print["Increase n"]
]
```

Constraints verification

```
{D[px, x] - 1, D[px, x, x] - 0, D[px, x, x, x] - 0,  D[px, x, x, x, x] - 0} /. {x -> 0}
{px - 1, D[px, x] - 1, D[px, x, x] - 0, D[px, x, x, x] - 0, D[px, x, x, x, x] - 0} /. {x -> xmax}
rest /. sol
```

Comment: This solution is only numerically correct, right ? You do not check that the solution is monotonic in an absolute sense, you only check that it is monotonic on a finite set of values.